# How display success message after submit the form

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, forms, helper, messages

How display success a message after submit the form.
This is my site [a link](http://www.poney.com.my/poney-card)

Comment: Going to need a lot more information than that to give an answer that is actually useful.

Answer (score 16):

In php this type of work implement on session variable.

Magento is doing by

set `success message`  using `->addSuccess('YOUR MSG');`.

and  set `error message`  using `->addError('YOUR ERROR MSG')`

**Those magento  functions are  Object of**

1. `Mage::getSingleton('core/session'`)
2. `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')`
3. `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')`

So you can set this message.

1. `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('YOUR MSG');`
2. `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess('YOUR MSG');`

etc

This message is shown **at phtml file using  add below code:**

```
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
```

**Most Important Note:**

This session message `is one available up to one render`.

ON  Message `display page` ,you need  to `initialized`  this session  using code `initLayoutMessages()` and you need  add this code  before `$this->renderLayout();` function i.e Start of render layout

Just like:

```
  $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
  $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
```

Suppose you have set message at  `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')` and on message display page you have not initialized `$this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');`

Then **you did not get this message.**

**A Good example is contact page:**

```
public function postAction()
{
   ........
    if ( $post ) {
        $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
        /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
        $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
        try {
       .............
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');

            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

    } else {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Message is show at `indexAction`:

```
  public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')
            ->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') );

        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Having to initialize the messages put me on the track !

Comment: Thx, I have the problem that on product view there is no error message shown. So the reason is because that message is already shown in `customer/account/login` i guess... So I had to solve it at another way. I could also just redirect the user to the login page but I wanted him to stay on the product. I tried to add `$this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');` and `$this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');` to the `_prepareLayout` function of the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` in `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View.php` but then the site stopped working.

Answer (score 6):

> 1. Set Your Message.

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addSuccess("Add success message"); 
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addError("Please login");
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addNotice("Add notification message");
```

> 2. Display Your Message Whereever You Want.(Optional If use custom Extension Or not Defined)

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages'); ?>
```

> 3.Define Block in Layout. (Optional If use custom Extension Or not Defined)

`<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>`

Answer (score 1):

To display a success message use `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess()`

Take a look at /app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php

```
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ( $post ) {
        try {
            $postObject = new Varien_Object();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            //save to db or email

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
    } else {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
```